# Why are shellfish not kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, fish

I have tried to read up and understand why shell fish aren't kosher, but the reasoning for scales/fins seems to be able to apply to shellfish as well. Is there any logical explanation?

Comment: Hi Luple, welcome to Mi Yodeya! I suppose you just gave the answer yourself. There are criteria for animals to be kosher, but there is no reasoning of the Torah behind them. Try to Google the word _chok._

Comment: In what way does the reasoning seem to apply?

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question.  @Luple is not asking *which* sea creatures are not kosher, but rather *why*.  The answer may be, we don't know.  There have certainly been attempts to explain it based on health issues (of the waters they come from) but that doesn't really fit.  Are there historical answers?  Other cultures that also eschew shellfish?  Any specific physical or spiritual reasons for it, other than "G-d said so"?

Comment: @cyn maybe that's what he's asking. There's no way to know unless he clarifies.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95340/is-this-squid-with-scales-kosher

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Luple. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shellfish do not have fins and scales. As the pasuk [Shmini 11:9](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9912#showrashi=true) says

> Among all [creatures] that are in the water, you may eat these: Any
>   [of the creatures] in the water that has fins and scales, those you
>   may eat, whether [it lives] in the waters, in the seas or in the
>   rivers.

**Rashi explains:

> **fins:** Heb. סְנַפִּיר. These are [the wing-like appendages] with which it swims [namely, fins].
>
> scales: Heb. קַשְׂקֶשֶׂת. These are the scales that are affixed to it,
>   as it is said: “And he was wearing a coat of mail (קַשְׂקַשִּׂים) ” (I
>   Sam. 17:5), [lit. armor of scales]. — [Chul. 66b]

The next pasuk is explicit.

> But any [creatures]that do not have fins and scales, whether in the
>   seas or in the rivers, among all the creeping creatures in the water
>   and among all living creatures that [live] in the water, are an
>   abomination for you.

This means that any sea creature of any type that does not have fins **and** scales is forbidden. This includes not only shell fish, but all other creatures living in the water (whether salt or fresh water). That is why sharks, dolphins and other sea creatures are forbidden.